# Express missing properties when using typescript: rawBody

Tags: typescript, express

I am getting this console error when compiling:

```
Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

On this line of code:

```
busboy.end(req.rawBody);
```

Which these [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) state should be there. But as soon as I changed to typescript, I got an error.

The code still runs in locally when I serve the function, but I would like to know what is going on, why and how to clear the type errors. As if I ignoring them, why am I using TS, I should just go back to straight js.

Comment: You can use this: ```req['rawBody']``` instead of ```req.rawBody```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After my code where I call:

```
busboy.on("finish"), () => {
  <code in here>
});
```

I ended up using this instead of `busboy.end(req.rawBody);` :

```
req.pipe(busboy);
```

And now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Hitting this problem now. Typescript states it shouldn't be there, but it is. You can add things to the typescript definition of Express.Request like so (this is the same as multer does it)

```
import { Request, ParamsDictionary, NextFunction, Response } from "express-serve-static-core";
interface BusboyFile {
    fieldname: string
    file: NodeJS.ReadableStream | undefined
    filename: string;
    destination: string;
    encoding?: string,
    mimetype?: string
}
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            files: {
                [fieldname: string]: BusboyFile[];
            };
            rawBody: any
        }
    }
}

type uploadBusboy = (request: ExpressRequest<ParamsDictionary>, response: Response, next: NextFunction)=>void
```

then my function:

```
export const uploadBusboy: uploadBusboy = (request, response, next) => {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: request.headers });
    // ...code here
    busboy.end(request.rawBody);
}
export default uploadBusboy
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Firebase Cloud Function with Typescript, which throws this error as well.

My temporary fix is to use the `as` keyword to tell the compiler to consider the `req` object as another type when you accessing the `rawBody`.

Example

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express-serve-static-core"
import { https } from "firebase-functions";

type FirebaseRequest = https.Request

// The parameters still use the default types from express, 
// but consider it as another type when accessing rawBody
const myFunc = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const rawVar = (req as FirebaseRequest).rawBody;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You didn't provide any information about your code.
Make sure that you install body-parser and require it.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Comment: But I am using express, I thought I read body-parser was added to express at some point?

Comment: Body-parser is part from express, but its not a default installed, other wise each of the addons would make express very big. Its just a middleware that you can add ontop of your express application, some need cookie-parser for instance and not body-parser. So you dont have to work around, just install body-parser and use it as middleware. Good luck